# Compiler error: final link failed: bad value collect2.exe

Tags: esp32, compiler

I work With VS Code v:1.59.1.
With extension vscode-arduino v:0.4.4

befor update of vscode. in version 1.58. all was ok. I can build and upload code for all mucrocontrollers.

but after the update, I can build code for arduino uno.
but when i build the code for esp32, i get this error:

```
[Starting] Analyzing sketch 'emptyProjct.ino'
[Warning] Output path is not specified. Unable to reuse previously compiled files. Build will be slower. See README.
Cargando configuración...
Inicializando paquetes...
Preparando tarjetas...
Verficando...
c:/users/hassan daoud/documents/arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: bad value
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
IntelliSense configuration already up to date. To manually rebuild your IntelliSense configuration run "Ctrl+Alt+I"
[Error] Analyzing sketch 'emptyProjct.ino': Exit with code=1
```

other thing. in the right of status bar. in [Select Programmer], I can't show any programmer for ESP32, but when i change board to arduino uno, i can select from a lot of choises.

this screenshot is for adruino uno.
[image]

and this is for esp32 wroom
[image]

after the update of vscode I try to download another extension like [Espressif IDF]. because [vscode-arduino] dont fix the error of serial port.

I contact with [Espressif IDF] for an error in instalation and him tel me to download the sdk in a path with out spasing. and then its work. but the old library I download from Arduino IDE for ESP32 its work in the prev. ver.
with space in the path.

so I dont know if the problem is from the new library or what happen. but I cant build code for ESP32.

please help me
thank you a lot to all.

Comment: I deeply suspect this is a duplicate of something.  But, you have a space in your user account name that appears to be messing with the build process.  See `c:/users/hassan daoud` and `Usado: C:\Users\Hassan`.

Comment: @timemage. yes but before last update to v1.59. its work properly.

Comment: It might be a regression worth to be submitted to some bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fix the error.

I remove all library for esp32 in my computer

```
c:/users/hassan daoud/documents/arduino/hardware/
c:/users/hassan daoud/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/
```

and install again from board manager.

all work ok